# Add more dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have, by default, one select box that Car:

```
<select name="cars[]">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But I'd like a link that says "Add another car" which will create an identical dropdown box, so that when it submits it will be cards[0] = Value and cars[2] value on submit. Each time the user hits "Add another car" they can create a new dropdown box as much as they'd like.

Comment: Taking into account that this is pretty much the default option box from w3schools, what have you tried or researched about this?

Comment: So what have you tried? You seem to have omitted the JavaScript that you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_clonenode.asp) creates an exact copy of a specified node.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var onAddClick = function() {
  var clone = document.getElementById('cars').cloneNode(true);
  clone.removeAttribute('id');
  container.appendChild(clone);
};
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', onAddClick);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <select name="cars[]" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
```